# I am trying to create a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and a custom Adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to create a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and a custom `Adapter` but the images don't appear. I am stuck and don't know what's wrong

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.Mo`viesHolder> {
    Context context;

    ArrayList<String> mImages;
    ArrayList<String> mTitle ;
    ArrayList<String> mReleaseDate;
    ArrayList<String> mSynopsis;
    ArrayList<Double> mAverageRating;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mImages, ArrayList<String> mTitle, ArrayList<String> mReleaseDate, ArrayList<String> mSynopsis, ArrayList<Double> mAverageRating) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        this.mReleaseDate = mReleaseDate;
        this.mSynopsis = mSynopsis;
        this.mAverageRating = mAverageRating;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MoviesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View movieView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_layout,parent,false);


        return new MoviesHolder(movieView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesHolder holder, final int position) {


        Glide.with(context)
             .asBitmap()
             .load(mImages.get(position))
             .into(holder.movieImage);


        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),MovieDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("movie_poster",mImages);
                intent.putExtra("movie_title",mTitle);
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return mImages.size();
    }

    public class MoviesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView movieImage;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        String movieTitle;
        String movieReleaseDate;
        String movieSynopsis;
        double movieAverageRating;

        public MoviesHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

         movieImage =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_img);
         parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView moviesRecycler;
    private ArrayList<String> mMoviePoster = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mMovieTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mMovieReleaseDate = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mMovieSynopsis = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> mMovieAverageRating = new ArrayList<>();


    MoviesAdapter myMoviesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initMovieDetails();


        moviesRecycler = findViewById(R.id.moviesRecycler);

        myMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this,mMoviePoster,mMovieTitle,mMovieReleaseDate,mMovieSynopsis,mMovieAverageRating);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

        moviesRecycler.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);
        moviesRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


    }

    private void initMovieDetails() {
        mMoviePoster.add("https://unsplash.com/photos/NhUJuPUeRvc");
        mMovieTitle.add("Parasite");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(8.6);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("A poor family, the Kims, con their way into becoming the servants of a rich family, the Parks. But their easy life gets complicated when their deception is threatened with exposure.\n");

        mMoviePoster.add("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8946378/mediaviewer/rm2569376769");
        mMovieTitle.add("Knives Out");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(8.0);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("A detective investigates the death of a patriarch of an eccentric, combative family.\n");

        mMoviePoster.add("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1051906/mediaviewer/rm1847823873");
        mMovieTitle.add("The Invisible Man");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(7.6);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("When Cecilia's abusive ex takes his own life and leaves her his fortune, she suspects his death was a hoax. As a series of coincidences turn lethal, Cecilia works to prove that she is being hunted by someone nobody can see.\n");

        mMoviePoster.add("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7286456/mediaviewer/rm3353122305");
        mMovieTitle.add("Joker");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(8.6);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("In Gotham City, mentally troubled comedian Arthur Fleck is disregarded and mistreated by society. He then embarks on a downward spiral of revolution and bloody crime. This path brings him face-to-face with his alter-ego: the Joker.\n");

        mMoviePoster.add("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2584384/mediaviewer/rm3972044545");
        mMovieTitle.add("JoJo Rabbit");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(8.0);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("A young boy in Hitler's army finds out his mother is hiding a Jewish girl in their home.\n");

        mMoviePoster.add("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8579674/mediaviewer/rm144738817");
        mMovieTitle.add("1917");
        mMovieReleaseDate.add("2019");
        mMovieAverageRating.add(8.4);
        mMovieSynopsis.add("April 6th, 1917. As a regiment assembles to wage war deep in enemy territory, two soldiers are assigned to race against time and deliver a message that will stop 1,600 men from walking straight into a deadly trap.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: URLs are HTML pages, not actual images ;) right click on the image and select "copy image address" inside your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the URL you are assigning to Glide. These links are HTML/CSS or etc ..., you should assign the image itself for Glide. 
For example, try to replace all URLs with the following URL: 
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjU0Yzk2MzEtMjAzYy00MzY0LTg2YmItM2RkNzdkY2ZhN2JkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDg4NjY5OTQ@._V1_SY1000_SX667_AL_.jpg

This URL is .jpg extension. I believe it should work, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should move this line 
    moviesRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); on top of 
    moviesRecycler.setAdapter(myMoviesAdapter);

and it is better to use model class